# Split a string based on a regex? pattern in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a string separated by a date and a colon: `01/12/2016:Something happened.02/12/2016:Something else happened.`

I need to be able to split the string which could have many dates by the pattern of 'dd/MM/yyyy:' without removing the deliminator itself. I can write some long winded loop. I was just wondering if there is a more elegant solution to detecting the pattern?

Edit:
As I work on trying to get to the answer I have found that this works to keep the colon in as I only know how to write a single delimiter Im not sure how to write the pattern to capture the data, which I would think would look for the slashes in the date to define it along the numbers between?

```
  Dim AllDatedProfiles() = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(PRofile, "(?=[:])")
```

Comment: If the date format is fixed and there are no colons in the rest of the string, just find the colons and use the previous 10 characters to parse the date.

Comment: the date format is fixed, however there could be colons in the text. The only thing that will not repeat is a date and colon unless it is part of the next report. Also it could have several full stops in one report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desperation breeds action! I have been for so long puzzled by the regex but I came across some tutorials that broke down all the hieroglyphics and its not hard at all to construct simple pattern recognition. Took me 20 min to learn and 5 min to do! If you are like me, do yourself a favor and watch a vid or something and learn this! Thanks all that partook.

```
Dim AllDatedProfiles() = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(PRofile, "(?=[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2,4}:)")
```